# Android Styles throw error while using appcompat-v7:23.0.1

Tags: android, material-design

I just created a new project in android studio, but it immediately threw the following errors pointing to v23/values-v23.xml file.
 1
1. Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
2. Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Add your full log here..!!

Comment: remove parent theme from style tag.

Comment: the console output is:

Comment: Which build version you are using???

Comment: Error Code:
 1
Output:
 C:\...\...\AndroidStudioProjects\...\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v23\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
 
 C:\...\...\AndroidStudioProjects\...\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v23\values.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Comment: I'm using:  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

Comment: if you are using buildToolsVersion "21.1.2" make sure to import same version appcompact compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.2.1' just like this..

Comment: Or change the buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1

Comment: @preethi you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first change your `buildToolsVersion`

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
   // applicationId "package name"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

or set `buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1`

Comment: that's great, it worked. Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya and the team

Comment: @kabs happy to hear .Move ahead

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before a while , I changed compileSDKVersion to 23 , It worked for me .Here is app.gradle file . You can try this .

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```